# How can I install mosek solver in matlab for free?

Tags: matlab, installation

What is 'mosek solver' in matlab?I have tried serveral ways but can't install it,how can I install 'mosek solver' for free?
Is there any way?

Comment: add some more details!

Answer (score 2):

[MOSEK](https://www.mosek.com/) is a Toolbox for MATLAB capable of solving large-scale optimization problems including linear, convex quadratic, conic quadratic (also known as second-order cone), semidefinite, and general convex.

**You can install it by following these steps:**
https://docs.mosek.com/9.0/toolbox/install-interface.html

Comment: Do I need to register an account?

Comment: No, you don't need an account to download MOSEK: https://download.mosek.com/stable/8.1.0.80/mosektoolswin64x86.zip

Comment: You sure about that? They may have left their download link open, but the [MOSEK Licensing Guide](https://docs.mosek.com/9.0/licensing/intro.html) says "The MOSEK Optimization Suite is a commercial product that requires a valid license." And their [Pricing Guide](https://www.mosek.com/sales/commercial-pricing/) says licenses start at $2,000.

Comment: Thank you all,I have solved the problem,and another link:https://www.mosek.com/products/academic-licenses/